# How to expand a pandas column with a list of dictionaries into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several columns in my pandas dataframe that contain a nested list of dictionaries. An example is as follows in column `Return.ReturnData.IRS990.ProgramServiceRevenueGrp`:

```
[{'Description': 'TUITION', 'BusinessCode': '611610', 'TotalRevenueColumn': '99612', 'RelatedOrExemptFunctionIncome': '99612'}, {'Description': 'ART EVENT', 'BusinessCode': '711190', 'TotalRevenueColumn': '18759', 'RelatedOrExemptFunctionIncome': '18759'}, {'Description': 'SALES', 'BusinessCode': '453220', 'TotalRevenueColumn': '8236', 'RelatedOrExemptFunctionIncome': '8236'}, {'Description': 'SUPPLY FEE', 'BusinessCode': '453220', 'TotalRevenueColumn': '6784', 'RelatedOrExemptFunctionIncome': '6784'}, {'Description': 'TICKETS', 'BusinessCode': '711190', 'TotalRevenueColumn': '1644', 'RelatedOrExemptFunctionIncome': '1644'}]
```

It's a little bit difficult to read but this list contains five dictionaries that all have the same keys (occasionally some are missing but that should be irrelevant.) Since the column is named:`Return.ReturnData.IRS990.ProgramServiceRevenueGrp` I'd like to create a new column for every dictionary in the original column, so for example:

`Return.ReturnData.IRS990.ProgramServiceRevenueGrp1` will contain:

```
{'Description': 'TUITION', 'BusinessCode': '611610', 'TotalRevenueColumn': '99612', 'RelatedOrExemptFunctionIncome': '99612'}
```

and `Return.ReturnData.IRS990.ProgramServiceRevenueGrp5` will contain:

```
{'Description': 'TICKETS', 'BusinessCode': '711190', 'TotalRevenueColumn': '1644', 'RelatedOrExemptFunctionIncome': '1644'}
```

There aren't always 5 dictionaries in a list though, sometimes there are more and less. What is the best way to accomplish this? Also, some of the values in the column are NaN so I'd like to transfer those so it looks something like this:

```
original column           new column
list                      dict
NaN                       NaN
NaN                       NaN
list                      dict
NaN                       NaN
```

I appreciate any feedback, and please note that this has to be done for 143 columns so I'd  rather not do it by hand.

```
EDIT: expected final result:

#       original column
1       nan
2       [2 dicts]
3       nan
4       [4 dicts]
...
8229    [3 dicts]

expanded:
#     col1     col2     col3     col4  
1     nan      nan      nan      nan
2     dict     dict     nan      nan
3     nan      nan      nan      nan
4     dict     dict     dict     dict
...
8229  dict     dict     dict     nan
```

So I need to test to see if the value is nan or dict first and each column should have the same number of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I'm familiar with your data from another question, and it still applies that working with heavily nested JSON data is a pain.
- The column names are really long, and that makes them difficult to deal with.
- Creating a new column for each `dict` inside the list, requires creating the same number of new columns as there are values inside the list. In this example there are 5, which means 5 new column names.

  - A list comprehension is used to create the number of new column names, based on the length of the largest list in the column.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Return.ReturnData.IRS990.ProgramServiceRevenueGrp': [[{'Description': 'TUITION', 'BusinessCode': '611610', 'TotalRevenueColumn': '99612', 'RelatedOrExemptFunctionIncome': '99612'}, {'Description': 'ART EVENT', 'BusinessCode': '711190', 'TotalRevenueColumn': '18759', 'RelatedOrExemptFunctionIncome': '18759'}, {'Description': 'SALES', 'BusinessCode': '453220', 'TotalRevenueColumn': '8236', 'RelatedOrExemptFunctionIncome': '8236'}, {'Description': 'SUPPLY FEE', 'BusinessCode': '453220', 'TotalRevenueColumn': '6784', 'RelatedOrExemptFunctionIncome': '6784'}, {'Description': 'TICKETS', 'BusinessCode': '711190', 'TotalRevenueColumn': '1644', 'RelatedOrExemptFunctionIncome': '1644'}]]})

# create a list of new column names
col = 'Return.ReturnData.IRS990.ProgramServiceRevenueGrp'
max_col_list_len = df.loc[:, col].map(len).max()  # max length of all lists in column
new_cols = [f'{col}{i}' for i in range(1, max_col_list_len + 1)]

# new_cols
['Return.ReturnData.IRS990.ProgramServiceRevenueGrp1',
 'Return.ReturnData.IRS990.ProgramServiceRevenueGrp2',
 'Return.ReturnData.IRS990.ProgramServiceRevenueGrp3',
 'Return.ReturnData.IRS990.ProgramServiceRevenueGrp4',
 'Return.ReturnData.IRS990.ProgramServiceRevenueGrp5']

# split the column of lists into multiple columns
df[new_cols] = pd.DataFrame(df[col].tolist(), index= df.index)

# drop the old column if desired
df.drop(columns=col, inplace=True)

# display(df)
                                                                              Return.ReturnData.IRS990.ProgramServiceRevenueGrp1                                                                               Return.ReturnData.IRS990.ProgramServiceRevenueGrp2                                                                         Return.ReturnData.IRS990.ProgramServiceRevenueGrp3                                                                              Return.ReturnData.IRS990.ProgramServiceRevenueGrp4                                                                           Return.ReturnData.IRS990.ProgramServiceRevenueGrp5
0  {'Description': 'TUITION', 'BusinessCode': '611610', 'TotalRevenueColumn': '99612', 'RelatedOrExemptFunctionIncome': '99612'}  {'Description': 'ART EVENT', 'BusinessCode': '711190', 'TotalRevenueColumn': '18759', 'RelatedOrExemptFunctionIncome': '18759'}  {'Description': 'SALES', 'BusinessCode': '453220', 'TotalRevenueColumn': '8236', 'RelatedOrExemptFunctionIncome': '8236'}  {'Description': 'SUPPLY FEE', 'BusinessCode': '453220', 'TotalRevenueColumn': '6784', 'RelatedOrExemptFunctionIncome': '6784'}  {'Description': 'TICKETS', 'BusinessCode': '711190', 'TotalRevenueColumn': '1644', 'RelatedOrExemptFunctionIncome': '1644'}
```

## For many columns

```py
for col in df.columns:  # can also be a list with specific column(s), instead of df.columns
    values = df[col].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)  # drop all NaN from the column
    if type(values[0]) == list:  # checks the first row to see if the column now has a list after having removed NaNs
        df[col] = df[col].fillna({i: [] for i in df.index})  # replace all the NaNs with an empty list; .fillna([]) doesn't work
        max_col_list_len = df.loc[:, col].map(len).max()  # determine max list length for all rows in column
        new_cols = [f'{col}.{i}' for i in range(1, max_col_list_len + 1)]  # create new column names
        df[new_cols] = pd.DataFrame(df[col].tolist(), index= df.index)  # create new column for each value in list
        df = df.drop(columns=col)  # drop original column
```

### Test

```py
# test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [np.nan, [{'k': 'v'}, {'k': 'v'}], [{'k': 'v'}, {'k': 'v'}, {'k': 'v'}]], 'col2': [[{'k': 'v'}, {'k': 'v'}], [{'k': 'v'}, {'k': 'v'}, {'k': 'v'}], np.nan], 'col3': ['v1', 'v2', 'v3']})

# display(df)
                                   col1                                  col2 col3
0                                   NaN              [{'k': 'v'}, {'k': 'v'}]   v1
1              [{'k': 'v'}, {'k': 'v'}]  [{'k': 'v'}, {'k': 'v'}, {'k': 'v'}]   v2
2  [{'k': 'v'}, {'k': 'v'}, {'k': 'v'}]                                   NaN   v3

# run it through the loop
# display(df)  # updated
  col3      col1.1      col1.2      col1.3      col2.1      col2.2      col2.3
0   v1        None        None        None  {'k': 'v'}  {'k': 'v'}        None
1   v2  {'k': 'v'}  {'k': 'v'}        None  {'k': 'v'}  {'k': 'v'}  {'k': 'v'}
2   v3  {'k': 'v'}  {'k': 'v'}  {'k': 'v'}        None        None        None
```

Comment: Worked brilliantly, thank you so much for the clear insight!